# Collectives icon will be lost if the request is canceled during inline tag editing

Tags: bug, collectives, inline-tag-editor

While editing the tags using the [inline tag editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) option, if you "Cancel" the request, we will lose the collectives icon in the display.

**GIF for reference:**

> [image: Collectives icon lost]